# R Shiny, - Passing Multiple User Inputs into a single dataframe in server

Tags: r, shiny, quantitative-finance, shiny-reactivity

I must admit I am relatively new to R-Shiny so apologies if this is a very basic question.

I am trying to create an R-Shiny app which takes in user inputs in relation to an asset class' expected annual return, maximum weight and minimum weight. Ideally I would like to end up with a server dataframe similar to the below, with the expected returns and weights configurable:

| Asset Class | Expected_Return | Max_Weight | Min_Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Equity | 0.08 | 1.00 | 0.25 |
| Bonds | 0.02 | 0.75 | 0.10 |
| Gold | 0.03 | 0.20 | 0.00 |
| Property | 0.05 | 0.30 | 0.00 |
| Cash | 0.01 | 0.10 | 0.00 |

My UI code:

```
library(shiny)



ui <- fluidPage(
   fluidRow(
       column(width = 1, align="center",
              checkboxInput("equity_include", "Equity", value = TRUE, width = '100%')
       ),
       column(width = 5, align="center",
              numericInput("equity_er", "Global Expected Annual Return (%)", value = 0)
       ),
       column(width = 3, align="center",
              numericInput("equity_maxw", "Max Weight %", value = 100, min = 0, max = 100)
       ),
       column(width = 3, align="center",
              numericInput("equity_minw", "Min Weight %", value = 0, min = 0, max = 100)
       )
   ),
   fluidRow(
       column(width = 1, align="center",
              checkboxInput("bonds_include", "Bonds", value = TRUE, width = '100%')
       ),
       column(width = 5, align="center",
              numericInput("bonds_er", "Bonds Expected Annual Return (%)", value = 0)
       ),
       column(width = 3, align="center",
              numericInput("bonds_maxw", "Max Weight %", value = 100, min = 0, max = 100)
       ),
       column(width = 3, align="center",
              numericInput("bonds_minw", "Min Weight %", value = 0, min = 0, max = 100)
       )
   ),
   fluidRow(
       column(width = 1, align="center",
              checkboxInput("gold_include", "Gold", value = TRUE, width = '100%')
       ),
       column(width = 5, align="center",
              numericInput("gold_er", "Gold Expected Annual Return (%)", value = 0)
       ),
       column(width = 3, align="center",
              numericInput("gold_maxw", "Max Weight %", value = 100, min = 0, max = 100)
       ),
       column(width = 3, align="center",
              numericInput("gold_minw", "Min Weight %", value = 0, min = 0, max = 100)
       )
   ),
   fluidRow(
       column(width = 1, align="center",
              checkboxInput("property_include", "Property", value = TRUE, width = '100%')
       ),
       column(width = 5, align="center",
              numericInput("property_er", "Property Expected Annual Return(%)", value = 0)
       ),
       column(width = 3, align="center",
              numericInput("property_maxw", "Max Weight %", value = 100, min = 0, max = 100)
       ),
       column(width = 3, align="center",
              numericInput("property_minw", "Min Weight %", value = 0, min = 0, max = 100)
       )
   ),
   fluidRow(
       column(width = 1, align="center",
              checkboxInput("cash_include", "Cash", value = TRUE, width = '100%')
       ),
       column(width = 5, align="center",
              numericInput("cash_er", "Cash Expected Annual Return(%)", value = 0)
       ),
       column(width = 3, align="center",
              numericInput("cash_maxw", "Max Weight %", value = 100, min = 0, max = 100)
       ),
       column(width = 3, align="center",
              numericInput("cash_minw", "Min Weight %", value = 0, min = 0, max = 100)
       )
   ),
)
```

My Server Code:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    library("tidyverse")
    library(plotly) # To create interactive charts
    library(timetk) # To manipulate the data series
    
    #Create Dataframe of User Inputs
    assets <- c("Equity", "Bonds", "Gold", "Property", "Cash")
    include <- c(input$equity_include, input$bonds_include, input$gold_include, input$property_include, input$cash_include)
    expected_return <- c(input$equity_er, input$bonds_er, input$gold_er, input$property_er, input$cash_er)
    max_weight <- c(input$equity_maxw, input$bonds_maxw, input$gold_maxw, input$property_maxw, input$cash_maxw)
    min_weight <- c(input$equity_minw, input$bonds_minw, input$gold_minw, input$property_minw, input$cash_minw)
    
    user_inputs <- data.frame(assets, include, expected_return, max_weight, min_weight)
```

Unfortunately I am getting multiple reactivity errors which I have been unable to resolve using the typical reactive() function.

I'd really appreciate any help you may be able to offer on this issue.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know answers are usually supposed to solve your specific problem but I am quite lazy to type all those defaults, you can do this with editable data frames, I like to use the DT package for this

example based on:https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dt_output = function(title, id) {
  fluidRow(column(
    12, h1(paste0('Table ', sub('.*?([0-9]+)$', '\\1', id), ': ', title)),
    hr(), DTOutput(id)
  ))
}
render_dt = function(data, editable = 'cell', server = TRUE, ...) {
  renderDT(data, selection = 'none', server = server, editable = editable, ...)
}

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Double-click to edit table rows',
    
    dt_output('server-side processing (editable = "row")', 'x6'),
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    d6 = iris
    d6$Date = Sys.time() + seq_len(nrow(d6))
    
    options(DT.options = list(pageLength = 5))
    
    # server-side processing
    output$x6 = render_dt(d6, 'row')
    
    # edit a row
    observeEvent(input$x6_cell_edit, {
      d6 <<- editData(d6, input$x6_cell_edit, 'x6')
    })
    
})
```

Comment: Thanks a million, the editable data frame works much better than what I was originally trying to do. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the old approach surround the vector with reactive() and use then by calling the names like functions

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 1, align="center",
           checkboxInput("equity_include", "Equity", value = TRUE, width = '100%')
    ),
    column(width = 5, align="center",
           numericInput("equity_er", "Global Expected Annual Return (%)", value = 0)
    ),
    column(width = 3, align="center",
           numericInput("equity_maxw", "Max Weight %", value = 100, min = 0, max = 100)
    ),
    column(width = 3, align="center",
           numericInput("equity_minw", "Min Weight %", value = 0, min = 0, max = 100)
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 1, align="center",
           checkboxInput("bonds_include", "Bonds", value = TRUE, width = '100%')
    ),
    column(width = 5, align="center",
           numericInput("bonds_er", "Bonds Expected Annual Return (%)", value = 0)
    ),
    column(width = 3, align="center",
           numericInput("bonds_maxw", "Max Weight %", value = 100, min = 0, max = 100)
    ),
    column(width = 3, align="center",
           numericInput("bonds_minw", "Min Weight %", value = 0, min = 0, max = 100)
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 1, align="center",
           checkboxInput("gold_include", "Gold", value = TRUE, width = '100%')
    ),
    column(width = 5, align="center",
           numericInput("gold_er", "Gold Expected Annual Return (%)", value = 0)
    ),
    column(width = 3, align="center",
           numericInput("gold_maxw", "Max Weight %", value = 100, min = 0, max = 100)
    ),
    column(width = 3, align="center",
           numericInput("gold_minw", "Min Weight %", value = 0, min = 0, max = 100)
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 1, align="center",
           checkboxInput("property_include", "Property", value = TRUE, width = '100%')
    ),
    column(width = 5, align="center",
           numericInput("property_er", "Property Expected Annual Return(%)", value = 0)
    ),
    column(width = 3, align="center",
           numericInput("property_maxw", "Max Weight %", value = 100, min = 0, max = 100)
    ),
    column(width = 3, align="center",
           numericInput("property_minw", "Min Weight %", value = 0, min = 0, max = 100)
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 1, align="center",
           checkboxInput("cash_include", "Cash", value = TRUE, width = '100%')
    ),
    column(width = 5, align="center",
           numericInput("cash_er", "Cash Expected Annual Return(%)", value = 0)
    ),
    column(width = 3, align="center",
           numericInput("cash_maxw", "Max Weight %", value = 100, min = 0, max = 100)
    ),
    column(width = 3, align="center",
           numericInput("cash_minw", "Min Weight %", value = 0, min = 0, max = 100)
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(dataTableOutput("data_example"))
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  library("tidyverse")
  library(plotly) # To create interactive charts
  library(timetk) # To manipulate the data series
  
  #Create Dataframe of User Inputs
  assets <- c("Equity", "Bonds", "Gold", "Property", "Cash")
  include <- reactive(c(input$equity_include, input$bonds_include, input$gold_include, input$property_include,input$cash_include))
  expected_return <- reactive(c(input$equity_er, input$bonds_er, input$gold_er, input$property_er, input$cash_er))
  max_weight <- reactive(c(input$equity_maxw, input$bonds_maxw, input$gold_maxw, input$property_maxw, input$cash_maxw))
  min_weight <- reactive(c(input$equity_minw, input$bonds_minw, input$gold_minw, input$property_minw, input$cash_minw))
  
  #user_inputs <- data.frame(assets, include(), expected_return(), max_weight(), min_weight())
  output$data_example <- renderDataTable(data.frame(assets,include(),expected_return(),max_weight(),min_weight()))
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```